# Неправильное значение map при выполнении в нескольких потоках

Tags: java, многопоточность, map

Пишу программу которая считает количество повторений каждого слова в текстовом фаиле. В качестве теста взял текстовый фаил в котором, 12 раз повторяется слово "Привет".

```
class WordCountWithThread {

private static int i =0;

private static Map<String, Integer> mainMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    String PathToFile = "D:\\text1.txt";
    ArrayList<String> wordsTemp = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        File file = new File(PathToFile);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            i++;
            if (wordsTemp.size()<500000) {
                String FinalWord = convertedWord(scanner.next().toLowerCase());
                wordsTemp.add(FinalWord);
            }
            else if (wordsTemp.size()==500000){
                Runnable r = new NewThread(wordsTemp,mainMap);
                new Thread(r).start();
                wordsTemp = new ArrayList<String>();
                wordsTemp.add(convertedWord(scanner.next().toLowerCase()));
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (wordsTemp.size()>0){
        Runnable r = new NewThread(wordsTemp,mainMap);
        new Thread(r).start();
    }
    showResult(startTime);
}

// Создание второго потока
private static class NewThread implements Runnable {

    Thread thread;
    ArrayList <String> strings;
    Map<String, Integer> map;
    // Конструктор
    NewThread(ArrayList <String> strings,Map<String, Integer> map) {
        this.strings = strings;
        this.map = map;
        thread = new Thread(this, "Поток для примера");
        thread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        wordCount(strings, map);
    }
}

private static void wordCount(ArrayList<String> strings, Map<String, Integer> map) {
    String s;
    for (String string : strings) {
        s = string;
        if (string != null) {
            if (!map.containsKey(s)) {
                map.put(s, 1);
            } else {
                map.compute(s, (tokenKey, oldValue) -> oldValue == null ? 1 : oldValue + 1);
            }
        }
    };
    mainMap = map;
}

private static void showResult(long startTime){
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : mainMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + ":"
                + e.getValue());
    }
    System.out.println("Уникальных слов: "+mainMap.size());
    System.out.println("Всего слов: "+i);
    long timeSpent = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    System.out.println("программа выполнялась " + timeSpent + " миллисекунд");
}

//Преобразование
static String convertedWord(String word){
    return word.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");
}
```

В итоге выводит, что "Уникальных слов: 2". В чём может быть ошибка?

**EDIT** переписано на fork/join
class WordCountWithThread {

```
private static int i =0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Map<String, Integer> mainMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    String PathToFile = "D:\\text1.txt";
    ArrayList<String> wordsTemp = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        File file = new File(PathToFile);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            i++;
            if (wordsTemp.size()<500000) {
                String FinalWord = convertedWord(scanner.next().toLowerCase());
                wordsTemp.add(FinalWord);
            }
            else if (wordsTemp.size()==500000){
                WordCounter wordCounter = new WordCounter(wordsTemp,mainMap);
                ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
                pool.execute(wordCounter);
                wordsTemp = new ArrayList<String>();
                wordsTemp.add(convertedWord(scanner.next().toLowerCase()));
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (wordsTemp.size()>0) {
        WordCounter wordCounter = new WordCounter(wordsTemp,mainMap);
        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
        pool.execute(wordCounter);
        wordCounter.join();
    }
    showResult(startTime,mainMap);
}


private static void showResult(long startTime, Map<String, Integer> mainMap){

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : mainMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + ":"
                + e.getValue());
    }

    System.out.println("Уникальных слов: "+mainMap.size());
    System.out.println("Всего слов: "+i);
    long timeSpent = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    System.out.println("программа выполнялась " + timeSpent + " миллисекунд");
}

//Преобразование
static String convertedWord(String word){
    return word.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");
}
}

class WordCounter extends RecursiveTask<Map<String, Integer>> {

ArrayList <String> strings;
Map<String, Integer> map;

WordCounter(ArrayList<String> strings, Map<String, Integer> map) {
    this.strings = strings;
    this.map = map;
}

@Override
protected Map<String, Integer> compute() {
    String s;
    for (String string : strings) {
        s = string;
        if (string != null) {
                map.compute(s, (tokenKey, oldValue) -> oldValue == null ? 1 : oldValue + 1);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

После изменения выводит:
привет:1
привет:11
Уникальных слов: 2
Всего слов: 12
Стал правильно складывать map, но всё равно работает не правильно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы выводите результат не дожидаясь окончания работы потоков подсчета. 
Вставьте в методе `main` перед строкой

`showResult(startTime);`

строку

`Thread.sleep(1000);`

Разумеется это вариант для тестирования. Для рабочего варианта вам нужно организовать ожидание в основном потоке до отработки потоков подсчета.

**UPD:**

Посмотрите в сторону Fork/Join. С помощью его `RecursiveTask` можно организовать деление по потокам подсчета менее запутано и выполняться оно будет быстрее за счет использования всех доступных процессоров.

Comment: Лучше даже переписать немного и сделать join. Так надежнее и вернее.

Comment: @МаксимДробышев именно.

Comment: @GreyGoblin переписал, но ошибка осталась. (Код добавил выше)

Comment: @EgorChetvernin похоже у вас "приветы" различаются. Вероятно последний обрабатывается с каким-нибудь символом вроде возврата каретки или что-то вроде этого. Сравните в отладчике последнее и предпоследнее слово, поищите различия.

Answer (score 1):

Потокобезопасность `ConcurrentHashMap` означает атомарность каждой операции. В этом фрагменте кода выполняется не одна операция, а две:

```
if (!map.containsKey(s)) {
    map.put(s, 1);
} else {
    map.compute(s, (tokenKey, oldValue) -> oldValue == null ? 1 : oldValue + 1);
}
```

Между `containsKey` и `put` поток может задержаться, и в результате может записать единицу поверх результатов подсчета другого потока. Нужно использовать метод [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

```
map.merge(s, 1, Integer::sum ) // ключ, значение,
    // операция замены текущего значения f( old, new ), в данном случае сумма.
```

Про необходимость дождаться завершения всех ваших потоков вам уже сказали.

Answer (score 0):

Прочитайте про ключевое слово [synchronized](http://info.javarush.ru/CynepHy6/2014/10/27/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0.html).
Кстати чтобы программа выдавала точное время выполнения добавьте Thread(r).join();